# Methods for automated synonym detection

Tags: language-agnostic, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am currently working on a neural network based approach to short document classification, and since the corpuses I am working with are usually around ten words, the standard statistical document classification methods are of limited use. Due to this fact I am attempting to implement some form of automated synonym detection for the matches provided in the training. My question more specifically is about resolving a situation as follows:

Say I have classifications of "Involving Food", and one of "Involving Spheres" and a data set as follows:

```
"Eating Apples"(Food);"Eating Marbles"(Spheres); "Eating Oranges"(Food, Spheres);
"Throwing Baseballs(Spheres)";"Throwing Apples(Food)";"Throwing Balls(Spheres)";
"Spinning Apples"(Food);"Spinning Baseballs";
```

I am looking for an incremental method that would move towards the following linkages:

```
Eating --> Food
Apples --> Food
Marbles --> Spheres
Oranges --> Food, Spheres
Throwing --> Spheres
Baseballs --> Spheres
Balls --> Spheres
Spinning --> Neutral
Involving --> Neutral
```

I do realize that in this specific case these might be slightly suspect matches, but it illustrates the problems I am having. My general thoughts were that if I incremented a word for appearing opposite the words in a category, but in that case I would end up incidentally linking everything to the word "Involving", I then thought that I would simply decrement a word for appearing in conjunction with multiple synonyms, or with non-synonyms, but then I would lose the link between "Eating" and "Food". Does anyone have any clue as to how I would put together an algorithm that would move me in the directions indicated above?

Comment: You have a bunch of small sentences each with one of two labels, and you are looking for a way to associate each token in your vocabulary with the label it seems to be better related to or Neutral. Certain key terms are present in sentences coming from both labels, and you are trying to look for a clever way to give them the right label? Is that your question? Where do the notion of synonyms come into this whole paradigm?

Comment: This is only an example. In the actual implementation of this my sentences are considerably longer, and there are about 3000 labels, rather than the two. The synonym problem here is, perhaps using a loose definition of a synonym, but essentially being able to say that marbles are synonymous with spheres. I'm looking for thoughts on statistically incrementing words towards being synonyms in a pattern that would mimic that shown above.

Comment: Does it have to be a neural network? In your comments to steve's answer you seem to be open to alternative approaches (such as LDA), too (although you eventually dismissed LDA).

Comment: It does not need to be a neural network necessarily, so long as it is the right tool for the job. A neural network seemed most sensible to be, but if there is a better approach out there I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an unsupervized boot-strapping approach that was explained to me to do this.

There are different ways of applying this approach, and variants, but here's a simplified version.

### Concept:

Start by a assuming that if two words are synonyms, then in your corpus they will appear in similar settings. (eating grapes, eating sandwich, etc.)

(In this variant I will use co-occurence as the setting).

### Boot-Strapping Algorithm:

We have two lists,

- one list will contain the words that co-occur with food items
- one list will contain the words that are food items

#### Supervized Part

Start by seeding one of the lists, for instance I might write the word Apple on the food items list.

Now let the computer take over.

#### Unsupervized Parts

It will first find all words in the corpus that appear just before Apple, and sort them in order of most occuring.

Take the top two (or however many you want) and add them into the co-occur with food items list. For example, perhaps "eating" and "Delicious" are the top two.

Now use that list to find the next two top food words by ranking the words that appear to the right of each word in the list.

Continue this process expanding each list until you are happy with the results.

#### Once that's done

(you may need to manually remove some things from the lists as you go which are clearly wrong.)

#### Variants

This procedure can be made quite effective if you take into account the grammatical setting of the keywords.

```
Subj ate NounPhrase
NounPhrase are/is Moldy

The workers harvested the Apples. 
   subj       verb     Apples 

That might imply harvested is an important verb for distinguishing foods.

Then look for other occurrences of subj harvested nounPhrase
```

You can expand this process to move words into categories, instead of a single category at each step.

#### My Source

This approach was used in a system developed at the University of Utah a few years back which was successful at compiling a decent list of weapon words, victim words, and place words by just looking at news articles.

An interesting approach, and had good results.

Not a neural network approach, but an intriguing methodology.

#### Edit:

the system at the University of Utah was called AutoSlog-TS, and a short slide about it can be seen [here](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5340/slides/event_ie.4.pdf) towards the end of the presentation. And a link to a paper about it [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/research/techreports/2004/pdf/UUCS-04-015.pdf)

Comment: Well, this method isn't explicitly for a neural net, but the general method of finding similar words is the first method suggested here that is actually directly applicable to my problem. Again, this is definitely made for a larger corpus, but I think it should work if I make each seeding tree essentially an incrementation tree instead where a hit within a tree increments the link between the documents and the lack of a hit decrements it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try LDA which is unsupervised. There is a supervised version of LDA but I can't remember the name! Stanford parser will have the algorithm which you can play around with. I understand it's not the NN approach you are looking for. But if you are just looking to group information together LDA would seem appropriate, especially if you are looking for 'topics'

Comment: That seems like a good place to start, but one problem that I'm finding is that unlike in LDA, and in PLSI, where there is a definite separation between documents and topics, in my case they are the same, and it will require some tweaking to overcome, I will investigate calling my words topics, and my topics documents, but I don't know if that will work.

Comment: LDA will sadly not work for my application. I looked a good deal into it, and LDA requires a considerable amount of metadata concerning both topics, and words within those topics, and my documents simply are far too short for this metadata to be accessible. I also don't really have a need for the open chain of causality provided by LDA, though LDA does seem very cool and I will try to implement it on some project in the future.

Comment: What does LDA stand for? a google search doesn't bring anything useful up, nor does wikipedia recognize the acronym LDA as anything related, closest was Statistics for Latent Dirichlet Allocation, could that be what you mean?

Comment: Latent Dirichlet Allocation is in fact correct. If you're interested in similar things it's probably worth looking into PLSI (Probabalistic latent semantic indexing) and Pachinko allocation, Pachinko allocation is pretty new but seems to be surpassing LDA all around.

Answer (score 1):

The code here (http://ronan.collobert.com/senna/) implements a neural network to perform a variety on NLP tasks. The page also links to a paper that describes one of the most successful approaches so far of applying convolutional neural nets to NLP tasks.

It is possible to modify their code to use the trained networks that they provide to classify sentences, but this may take more work than you were hoping for, and it can be tricky to correctly train neural networks.

I had a lot of success using a similar technique to classify biological sequences, but, in contrast to English language sentences, my sequences had only 20 possible symbols per position rather than 50-100k.

One interesting feature of their network that may be useful to you is their word embeddings. Word embeddings map individual words (each can be considered an indicator vector of length 100k) to real valued vectors of length 50. Euclidean distance between the embedded vectors should reflect semantic distance between words, so this could help you detect synonyms.

For a simpler approach WordNet (http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) provides lists of synonyms, but I have never used this myself.

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing something, but it doesn't seem like senna is really the best tool for this. The closest thing to document classification they actually have benchmarks for it named entity recognition which is a very distinct problem. A very neat program yes, but unless I'm missing something, which I may be, it seems unrelated to my question. Especially since they have no notion of synonym identification. I already have the neural network part mapped out, but again this might just be my ignorance.

Comment: Figure 2 on page 8 of "Natural Language Processing (almost) from Scratch" shows their sentence approach network. You would need to modify the final layer to take your output categories.
Alternatively, you could try adding a lookup table layer to your network

Comment: Your criticisms are flawed.

Also, the word embeddings, which is what you should be interested in (and took 2 months to train), are included in the software package distributed by the authors.

Comment: Please explain why my criticisms are flawed if you would be so kind. Also their word embeddings were trained on a completely separate corpus from mine, and with that lack of domain specificity since I am working in a very particular domain they are essentially useless to me.

Comment: Here is an explanation of your critisms: (1) For features, the basic approach uses a dictionary of the 100k most common works from the Wall Street Journal corpus. The words are mapped to lowercase and a capitalization feature is added. This approach for creating feature vectors from words is basically the simplest you can get in NLP. NN's cannot be trained unless you map the input to some sort of vector representation (p.2477). (2) No small corpus data is presented in the paper. Only results from the 4 benchmark datasets for POS, Chunking, NER, and SRL.

Comment: Using only the basic features, their networks perform close to state- of-the-art. Using additional features the networks beat state-of-the-art performance for all but SRL (Table 10). Correctly trained word embeddings also improve performance. (3) The feature vector is basically the simplest possible, as I described in (1), all other parameters are learned by back-propagation. They bootstrap learning of the lookup-table (word-embeddings) because datasets for individual tasks are not large enough to train good vector representations.

Comment: (4) The longest training time they report is 7 weeks to train LM2 on the Wikipedia dataset. (end of section 4.3). The mention in the conclusion that if they tried to train a similar network 10 years ago, then it would probably still not have finished. (Other) I am not sure why you say that SENNA is not an NLP algorithm. It performs near or better than state of the art on 5 canonical NLP tasks! This is NLP.

Comment: Basically the whole point of the SENNA papers is to show that it is possible to learn intermediate representations (the hidden layers of the NNs) that allow excellent performance on different, but related, tasks. The word embeddings learned were trained so that the euclidean distance between embedding vectors are closely correlated with semantic distances between words in the English language. Unless the meanings of words in your task have no relationship to their meanings in the English language, the embeddings will work for your task.

Comment: You are also correct in that the raw SENNA architecture will not work directly for your task. However, a small modification to the network to map the output onto your set of categories is certainly possible. I have used this approach for biological sequences with great success.

Comment: What you are looking for is a set of category features for each word in your problem domain. The word embeddings from SENNA will work well as such features. So will the outputs from lower layers of the SENNA networks. You will not be able to find features that map words directly to your output categories. Finding such features means that you have already solved your classification problem.

Comment: Basically, adding any sets of features should improve your network's classification performance. You could use output from part-of-speech taggers or chunkers as additional input. You could use lists of synonyms. There are many other types of derived features that would help in classification.

Comment: So basically I just spent a few days deciding that you were right and that I should give it a try, and while you did bring up some valid points, after training senna to my output and my corpus for a few hours and running it for another day the hit rate was at about 60%. Also the reason something like this would work so well for biological sequences and so badly for synonym matching is for the reasons I articulated above. When matching biological sequences all of the features are explicit in the passed string, which is not so for synonym finding.

Comment: When you can train this framework on a gigantic corpus (Wikipedia) this wouldn't be such a huge issue, hence the great performance, but when your ratio of classifications to corpus length is very different from that, the lengthy training of senna is a lot less effective. When I said it was not an algorithm I meant just that, it is NLP, yes, but senna is a self-building architecture, not a raw algorithm and it uses already established algorithms for the actual nlp matching and whatnot, using itself only for feature extraction.

Comment: I also took your suggestion of implementing chunking and pos tagging and got a mild increase from the first and a more substantial decrease from the second (about 5% and 8% efficacy up and down respectively) which I suspect is because of my particular application. Nonetheless you clearly did a lot of research so even if it wasn't actually useful I don't think you deserve the downvote any more, and so if you edit your answer I can change that to an upvote for your efforts, but senna was really not the best choice.

Comment: I changed my response. Also, I recently found out about this site http://wordnet.princeton.edu/, which may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I misunderstand your question. Do you require the system to be able to reason based on your input data alone, or would it be acceptable to refer to an external dictionary?

If it is acceptable, I would recommend you to take a look at http://wordnet.princeton.edu/ which is a database of English word relationships. (It also exists for a few other languges.) These relationships include synonyms, antonyms, hyperonyms (which is what you really seem to be looking for, rather than synonyms), hyponyms, etc.

The hyperonym / hyponym relationship links more generic terms to more specific ones. The words "banana" and "orange" are hyponyms of "fruit"; it is a hyperonym of both. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy Of course, "orange" is ambiguous, and is also a hyponym of "color".

You asked for a method, but I can only point you to data. Even if this turns out to be useful, you will obviously need quite a bit of work to use it for your particular application. For one thing, how do you know when you have reached a suitable level of abstraction? Unless your input is hevily normalized, you will have a mix of generic and specific terms. Do you stop at "citrus","fruit", "plant", "animate", "concrete", or "noun"? (Sorry, just made up this particular hierarchy.) Still, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I've looked into wordnet, but as you mentioned it would require a lot of work for this application, and I have pretty bad experiences with wordnet for specificity. The synonym lookups are also dreadfully slow when you have to run them very often.

Comment: If wordnet had synsets that were well matched with my needs then yes this would be exactly what I need, but sadly wordnet loses a lot of precision to accommodate it's generality.