# How to find synonyms based on word2vec

Tags: word2vec

I 'm working on word2vec model using gensim in Python, but I found that the result are the words having the same theme, synonyms are only part of the result.

Can I find synonyms of a word based on the work I have done?

Any replies will be appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Word2vec tends to indicate similar words – but as you've probably seen, the kind of similarity it learns includes more than just pure synonyms.

For example, word2vec similarities include words that appear in similar contexts, such as alternatives including even opposites. (After all, 'hot' and 'cold' are very similar words in many ways – both adjectives, primarily relating to temperature, and also figuratively used in the same sorts of non-temperature contexts. Only in their contrast are they antonyms.)

You'll likely need to use other techniques (perhaps in concert with word2vec) for pure-synonym discovery.

Comment: Yes, I wonder what "other techniques" is. anyway, Thanks for your reply!

Comment: [automatic synonym identification] or [automatic synonym extraction] would be good queries to find academic papers proposing approaches – and one that surveys some approaches that include the use of word embeddings is <https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/pbml/105/art-leeuwenberg-et-al.pdf>. There's also another SO answer about the general task at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370247/methods-for-automated-synonym-detection

Comment: I will try these, Thanks a lot!

Comment: If we stick to an "out-of-the-box" word2vec model, eg using [TensforFlow tutorial with skip workds](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/word2vec), what's the expected performance regarding synonyms? In my understanding they would tend to appear in the same contexts, but rarely together (unless the corpus includes synonyms list or long sentences with rephrasing), so they might not be to distant but not close either?

Comment: You'd have to try it: every calculated set of word-vectors will be a bit different, based on training data, chosen parameters, etc. (But further: if you care about the quality of your word-vectors for other purposes, I'd highly recommend using a production-quality implementation with many config options, & lots of accumulated use by many people, rather than any 'tutorial'/educational demo implementation - which may have performance/quality/flexibility gotchas.)

Comment: But: in my experience, if your data/code/parameters work at all for word-vector training – you've supplied enough data, in the right format, to a working implementation, with sensible parameters – and you have word-vectors that seem to behave like others, then synonyms tend to wind up *very close* to each other. Indeed many of the oft-used tests of word-vector quality – gold-standard sets of words by human-perceived similarity – rely on that. …

Comment: … The fact that exact synonyms don't necessarily appear  near each other in texts doesn't overpower the model's trained-in tendency to place same-meaning words' vectors  very-near each other. Per earlier, you'd still have other closely-related words (even antonyms) quite-close in cosine-sim – word-vector-similarity isn't the exact same thing as 'synonymity' – but in well-trained word-vector sets, synonyms should be among the closest words to each other. (And, if they're not, you've probably got other problems in insufficient/insufficiently-varied data or misparameterized training.)

Answer (score 2):

```
import nltk
import gensim

nltk.download('word2vec_sample')

word2vec_sample = str(find('models/word2vec_sample/pruned.word2vec.txt'))

model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_sample, binary=False)

top=model.most_similar(positive=['cricket'], topn = 3)

print(top)
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Where to import `find()` ?