# Find synonyms of two word in wordnet in python

Tags: python, wordnet

I want to find out synonym of two words like : diabetes mellitus,menstrual disorders,prostate enlarged etc. 
since wordnet is working for single word, how do I do it for two words ?
any ideas ?

Comment: How are you doing it for one word?

Comment: (1) generate embeddings ( a numerical vector representation)  for each ngram (combination of words) (2) see which vectors are closest in the space of embeddings with an algorithm such as cosine-similarity ... this will require some work so do you research around word2vec, embedding and vector similarity... potential tools (sklearn, tensorflow, gensim, nltk) .. good luck

Comment: @AK47 using wordnet library , wordnet.synsets(word) .

Comment: @MedAli How word2vec helping in finding synonyms ? do you have any reference material ?

Comment: check this for information about word2vec https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/04/21/the-amazing-power-of-word-vectors/

Comment: @Jitesh What shows up if you try wordnet.synsets('diabetes_mellitu')

Comment: @Jitesh someone asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386503/how-to-find-synonyms-based-on-word2vec

Comment: @AK47 It giving me null

Comment: OK, it was just a wild guess as looking up wordnet.synsets('cat') seems to return ['cat', 'true_cat'] so was curious to see if it would work for underscoring multiple words